# Unconstrained Biases and Neural Network Regularization

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, improper-prior

In [Bishop's PRML](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) on page 259 he discusses a L2 regularizer for each layer of a 2-layer neural network, given by

$$
    \begin{equation}
    \frac{\lambda_1}{2}\sum_{w\in W_1}w^2 + \frac{\lambda_2}{2}\sum_{w\in W_2}w^2
    \end{equation}
$$

He then explains that this corresponds to the prior distribution

$$
    \begin{equation}
    p( w| \alpha_1, \alpha_2) \propto \exp{\left( -\frac{\alpha_1}{2} \sum_{w \in (1)}w^2 - \frac{\alpha_2}{2} \sum_{w \in (2)}w^2 \right)}
    \end{equation}
$$

which is "improper because the bias parameters are unconstrained."

I'm having trouble understanding why this distribution is improper, and why he considers the biases to be unconstrained?